# Install a package and import in the same python script

Tags: python, pip, subprocess

(Edit: I made a typo when writing this question: I put quotation mark around "pyparsing" in script. Thanks @dswdsyd)

When running a python script, there's only python standard library on target machine. When a package is needed, I have to install it first. For example, When I tried to install pyparsing and import it:

```
subprocess.call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "pyparsing"])    
import pyparsing
```

I got error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyparsing'
```

So how to install and import a package in the same python script?

[Update:] In the second run of the script, the package can be imported. Strange.

Comment: Noap, I still got "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyparsing'".

Comment: that is not reproducable , your provided code works just fine

Comment: Can you catch the stdout and stderr of the `subprocess` call and provide it?

Comment: subprocess works fine. Only import doesn't work at the first run. It works in a second run.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved by `importlib.invalidate_caches()`. According to importlib's documentation:

> importlib.invalidate_caches()
>
> Invalidate the internal caches of
> finders stored at sys.meta_path. If a finder implements
> invalidate_caches() then it will be called to perform the
> invalidation. This function should be called if any modules are
> created/installed while your program is running to guarantee all
> finders will notice the new module’s existence.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you are passing pyparsing as a variable instead of a string, to fix this change pyparsing to "pyparsing"

try this:

```
import subprocess
import sys
subprocess.call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "pyparsing"])    
import pyparsing
```

Comment: Ah my bad, thank you. I indeed put quotation mark around "pyparsing". The same error occur again.